# Dockerfile user creation permission not granted

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i am learning docker, i have created a Dockerfile like this :

```
FROM node:alpine    
RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S appuser && adduser -u 1001 -S appuser  -G appuser    
RUN apk update && apk add bash     
WORKDIR /usr/src/app    
COPY package*.json ./    
RUN npm install    
COPY ./wait-for-it.sh /usr/wait-for-it.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/wait-for-it.sh    
RUN chmod ugo+rwx /usr
RUN chown -R appuser:appuser /usr/src/app

USER appuser

COPY . .
```

And i have a docker-compose.override.yml like this

```
version: '3'    
services:
  main:
    command: bash -c "/usr/src/app/wait-for-it.sh --timeout=0 mongo:27017 && npm run dev"
    volumes:
      - ./api/src:/usr/src/app/src
```

this is giving error in  main container:

```
bash: /usr/src/app/wait-for-it.sh: Permission denied
```

Please help how can give permission to `appuser`. if i remove user creation everything works fine.

Comment: You must give the appuser permissions for the working directory ```chown -R appuser:appuser /usr/src/app```

Comment: And by the way, why are you creating a new user?

Comment: i learn that we should not run container as root user.

Comment: This line will also give a permissions error `RUN apk update && apk add bash sudo`

Comment: i have made some changes in dockerfile, now i am having error in wait-for-it.sh execution

Answer (score 0):

In docker it is common to run application containers as the root user. Remember this is the root user of the container not the host machine. If you do want to use a separate user to run the application within the container, I suggest you move the `USER` statement to the end of the Dockerfile and before that add a `chown` to update the ownership

Comment: i have made some changes in dockerfile, now i am having error in wait-for-it.sh execution.

Comment: Sounds like the same permissions error. You need to change the owner `chown` or change the permissions `chmod`

Comment: (The files _should_ be owned by the root user, so that a bug in the application code can't result in the files being accidentally modified.  Definitely don't make system-directories like `/usr` be world-writable.)